# kubernetes (rancher) ingress understanding

Tags: networking, kubernetes, service, rancher

**what i know / have running**:
i got a running rancher ha setup (2.4.2) on vsphere w/ a L4 nginx lb in front of it. access the ui and provision new clusters (vsphere node driver) works great. I know I'm not in the cloud and cannot use a L7 LB (apart from nip.ip or metal lb maybe), and deploying workloads and expose them via nodeport works great (so the workloads are available on the specified port on each node a according pod is running on).

**my question**:
is it possible to expose (maybe via ingress) applications on any of my running cluster under the domain/adress I can access the rancher ui (in my case: https://rancher-things.local)? like have external (local network, not public) if I would deploy maybe a harbor registry and can somehow expose it like https://rancherthings.local/harbor? or if this would not work is it possible to deploy a L4 load balancer for accessing applications on or in front of a specific cluster?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There should be ingress resource already which exposes the rancher ui. You can edit the ingress and add a path `/harbor` to route the traffic to service for harbor.

```
  paths:
  - path: /harbor
    backend:
      serviceName: harbor
      servicePort: 80
```

Answer (score 1):

@arghya-sadhu, the LB is pointing to the HA cluster (a.k.a upstream/management/rke/ha cluster) running Rancher, not Harbor. It's not recommended to create any other ingresses in this HA cluster. Also, I think the harbor workload is running in a downstream cluster and there is no LB pointing to the nodes of this cluster.

Patrick, you can create a service exposing your application port via http and use Rancher's proxy mechanism to access the UI of your app via the Rancher URL. If you have monitoring enabled in your setup, you can follow how Grafana UI is exposed via this mechanism.

After creating the service, you can find the URL info using the following command:

```
kubectl -n <your_app_namespace> cluster-info
# or
kubectl cluster-info -A
```

The downside of this approach is you don't have a dedicated LoadBalancer handling the traffic, but for smaller scale setup, this should be ok.

Example URL of grafana:

```
https://<rancher-fqdn>/k8s/clusters/<cluster-id>/api/v1/namespaces/cattle-prometheus/services/http:access-grafana:80
```

Comment: hi leo, ty but I think this approach dosent help me here because if try the example I have to login into rancher to access the url. I want to expose applications in my network without have systems or users to be loged in into rancher ui.. I want to deploy applications like harbor only on a downstream clusters. but I still wonder how to to this on prem with ingress..nodeport is working at least w/ chartmuseum for example. do I maybe have to spin up a nginx load balancer with a proper hostname in front of a downstream rancher cluster? thats the way i can acess the rancher ui from my ha setup

Comment: @PatrickHermann you are right, authentication is indeed needed. The above mentioned answer is specific to the OP's question was using a path under rancher UI. An external LB, like you mentioned, nginx, is needed for on-prem clusters. Creating a wildcard entry in nginx pointing to nodes of cluster, with a wildcard DNS entry pointing to the LB would give a lot of flexibility. Of course, you can do away with specific DNS entries instead of wildcard.

Comment: @leodotcloud Can you point us to a website explaining how one can actually expose a service through the Rancher proxy? Can't find any documentation regarding this topic.

Comment: @leodotcloud I think I've found a hint: https://github.com/rancher/charts/blob/main/charts/rancher-monitoring/values.yaml The official Rancher monitoring helm chart suggests that for each exposed service, a proxy container is added to the relevant workload pod. Now what I am missing is how to expose an existing workload pod through the Rancher proxy when there is an already existing deployment and the original helm chart can't be modified.

Comment: I managed to rebuild the proxy container stuff and got it working. I need to write this stuff down correctly and re-test this, so I can share the solution if required.

Comment: @PythonLearner Unfortunately, this information is not documented. Please feel free to create a PR here: https://github.com/rancher/docs with your findings, would be helpful for others.