# kubernetes (rancher) ingress for downstream cluster

Tags: rancher, k3s

##### What I know

I can access the service of a Rancher downstream cluster using the following URL:

`https://<rancher-server>/k8s/clusters/<cluster-id>/api/v1/namespaces/app-namespace/services/http:app-service:80/proxy/`

However, this URL can only be accessed when I am logged into the Rancher server.

##### What I want to do

If I want to access a service of a downstream cluster using the above URL without logging into the Rancher server, how can I achieve this?

##### Information I found

[kubernetes (rancher) ingress understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61345048/kubernetes-rancher-ingress-understanding/76419347#76419347)

However, I am still not sure what modifications or adjustments are needed for the proxy container. Can anyone provide a solution or guidance on this?

I have installed `Traefik Ingress Controller` on the downstream cluster and created an Ingress for the service as well.

Answer (score 1):

To access a service in a downstream cluster without logging in to the Rancher server, you can use an Ingress resource configured in the downstream cluster.

Here are the steps you can follow:

1. Install and configure Traefik Ingress Controller in your downstream cluster. You mentioned that you have already done this, so you should have Traefik running and configured.
2. Create an Ingress resource for your service in the downstream cluster. An Ingress defines rules for routing incoming requests to specific services. You can create an Ingress YAML file, similar to the following example:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  namespace: app-namespace
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: app-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

In this example, the Ingress routes incoming requests to the app-service in the app-namespace.

3. Apply the Ingress YAML file to your downstream cluster using kubectl or any other Kubernetes management tool: kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml. Make sure you are in the appropriate context for the downstream cluster.
4. Once the Ingress is created and applied successfully, you should be able to access the service using the URL configured in the Ingress. In your case, it would be something like: https:///.

Ensure you replace  with the actual URL or IP address of your downstream cluster.

By using this Ingress configuration, you won't need to access the Rancher server to reach your service. Instead, you can directly access it using the configured URL.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander for the quick response, As I said in the question, sorry I saw my question got a little bit formatted" I can access the service with `https://fqdn-rancher-cluster/k8s/clusters/cluster-id/api/v1/namespaces/wordpress/services/http:wordpress:80/proxy/`, WordPress being my app namespace for example. I am required to access the service without login to the cluster, Yes, what you said is right, I can access the service using the ingress URL or IP that points to the downstream cluster, but what I need is to access the WordPress app using the rancher URL, not the downstream URL.

Comment: @PythonLearner, It will be a great help, if you please explain what you did/changed/implemented to get your solution. Can you point me to some docs? I am looking for a similar solution. I really appreciate any help you can provide.